# Unable to call injectable function with a service instance. Parameter value always remains null

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an angular web app that uses access tokens that can expire. When they expire a 401 status response is sent back to the app which is then processed by a `retryWhen` operator. The logic for making a token refresh api call has been placed inside a injectable function that i declare in the `providers` array of `@NgModule(`

The function looks like this:

```
{ provide: 'tokenExpired', useValue: ({
  maxRetryAttempts = 1,
  loginService
}: {
  maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  loginService?:LoginService
} = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
  return attempts.pipe(
    concatMap((error, i) => {
      const retryAttempt = i + 1;
      if((error && error.headers && (!error.headers.get("reason-unauthorized") || !(error.headers.get("reason-unauthorized") === "authentication-token-expires-soon"))) || retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts) {
        return throwError(error);
      }
      loginService.requestNewToken().subscribe(success => {
        console.log(
          `Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${1000}ms`
        );
        return timer(50);
      }, 
      error => throwError(error));
    })
  );
} },
```

Its based on the tutorial i found here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen Only the author stored the logic into a exportable constant. I want to be able to inject this logic in all my httpClient services so thats why i chose to add it in the `providers` list.

Here is an example of how i call the retryWhen logic:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private injector: Injector,
    @Inject('tokenExpired') private tokenExpired: any,
    ) {}

  getSomeData():Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl + "/user/get/someData").pipe(retryWhen(this.tokenExpired(1, this.injector.get(LoginService)})));
```

This doesn't work. Despite getting the instance with an injector the loginService variable inside the tokenExpired logic remains null. Can anyone tell me how I can get this to work? I need a singleton
loginService instance, and if thats not possible, a singleton `HttpClient` object that i can use inside my `tokenExpired` function to call the refresh token api endpoint directly. The reason why it needs to be a singleton is because i don't want multiple api calls for different data calling the same refresh token api when each of them fails to get the data because of the token expiration. I want just one refresh token call of which the result is then distributed to all subscribers. I'm using the `share()` operator for that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `concatMap` where you use the following:

```
loginService.requestNewToken().subscribe(success => {
  console.log(`Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${1000}ms`);
  return timer(50);
},
```

This is not going to work because you have to return an Observable to `concatMap`. So maybe you could do something like this:

```
return loginService.requestNewToken()
  .pipe(
    concatMap(success => {
      console.log(`Attempt ${retryAttempt}: retrying in ${1000}ms`);
      return timer(50);
    }),
  );
```

It's hard to tell if somethings wrong with the rest. I'd have to make a reproducible demo.

Comment: doesent the timer under loginService.requestToken() already return an Observable?